# Getting higher execution times with increasing number of OMP threads

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm parallelizing the following block in order to compute the number of lethal accidents per week over a variable size (0.5M, 1M, 2M rows, etc.) dataset stored inside `localRows` which is a vector. The shared variables `local_lethAccPerWeek, local_accAndPerc, local_boroughWeekAcc` are arrays stored contiguously (e.g. `int local_lethAccPerWeek[NUM_YEARS][NUM_WEEKS_PER_YEAR] = {};`).

```cpp
    // [2] Data processing
    procBegin = MPI_Wtime();

    cout << "[Proc. " + to_string(myrank) + "] Started processing dataset..." << endl;
    omp_set_num_threads(num_omp_threads);
    int cfIndex, brghIndex;

// Every worker will compute in the final datastructure the num of lethal accidents for its sub-dataset and then Reduce it to allow the master to collect final results
#pragma omp parallel for default(shared) schedule(dynamic) private(cfIndex, brghIndex)
    for (int i = 0; i < my_num_rows; i++)
    {
        int lethal = (localRows[i].num_pers_killed > 0) ? 1 : 0;
        string borough = string(localRows[i].borough);
        int week, year, month = 0;

        if (lethal || !borough.empty())
        {
            week = getWeek(localRows[i].date);
            year = getYear(localRows[i].date);
            month = getMonth(localRows[i].date);

            // If I'm week = 1 and month = 12, this means I belong to the first week of the next year.
            // If I'm week = (52 or 53) and month = 01, this means I belong to the last week of the previous year.
            if (week == 1 && month == 12)
                year++;
            else if ((week == 52 || week == 53) && month == 1)
                year--;

            year = year - 2012;
            week = week - 1;
        }

        /* Query1 */
        if (lethal)
#pragma omp atomic
            local_lethAccPerWeek[year][week]++;

        /* Query2 */
        for (int k = 0; k < localRows[i].num_contributing_factors; k++)
        {
            cfIndex = cfDictionary.at(string(localRows[i].contributing_factors[k]));
#pragma omp critical(query2)
            {
                (local_accAndPerc[cfIndex].numAccidents)++;
                (local_accAndPerc[cfIndex].numLethalAccidents) += lethal;
            }
        }

        /* Query3 */
        if (!borough.empty()) // if borough is not specified we're not interested
        {
            brghIndex = brghDictionary.at(borough);
#pragma omp critical(query3)
            {
                local_boroughWeekAcc[brghIndex][year][week].numAccidents++;
                local_boroughWeekAcc[brghIndex][year][week].numLethalAccidents += lethal;
            }
        }
    }

    procDuration = MPI_Wtime() - procBegin;
```

I'm experiencing a strange behavior since increasing the omp threads gets me higher execution times. I'm aware that spawning threads increase the overhead due to context switches etc. and in some cases it can be way smoother to just let one thread do the job, but I don't see how parallelizing an operation of this kind (that's just an increment in the atomic section) could be worse. I've also tried changing out of curiosity the scheduling but of course doesn't help.

I'm asking you since you may see something that I'm missing.
Thanks in advance and please comment if you need further infos.

Comment: Assuming the lookup ("getNUmPersonsKilled") is cheap, there's hardly any work here, and much of what there is (the adjustment of the year and week) is potentially unnecessary (if there is no lethal accident you won't use the updated values anyway!) (On a stylistic point it's ***MUCH*** better to declare variables in the minimal scope (i.e. lethal, weak, year, month can all be declared inside the loop) rather using the OpenMP private annotation.

Comment: it isnt strange to see this effect. Putting more threads always decreases utilization and eventually you will observe slowdown due to more overhead than gains

Comment: I didn't mention that this is the first of three queries inside the same loop so I've updated the question for completeness. Anyhow, this means that (apart from a stylistic point of view) operations of this kind are "hardly parallelizable"? I'm still a bit confused about this as I would expect even for minimal weight operations that a parallelized for loop would improve execution.
@HighPerformanceMark I'm measuring them with ```MPI_Wtime()``` (i'm distributing work over N process each of them exploiting multithreading).

Comment: Also, since all three queries are independent from each other, could you tell me how better parallelism may be exploited? I'm thinking about adding sections inside and wrap them with ```omp parallel sections``` enabling nested parallelism but maybe there's a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several notes here:

1. You are using `schedule(dynamic)`. This means that every single iteration of the loop gets dispatched to a different thread on a first-come first-served basis. This adds a lot of overhead, especially if `my_num_rows` is large. It is better to work with chunks of iterations, say `N` iterations each, so try changing the schedule clause to `schedule(dynamic,N)`.

You have a lot of instances of true and false sharing where you nullify the benefits of having CPU caches due to the following two.

2. Atomic updates of shared variables are way slower in parallel than when done by a single thread, because the L1/L2 cache line holding the value gets constantly invalidated and reloaded from down the cache hierarchy. In a sequential program, the cache lines stay hot and the compiler can even apply register optimisations if it is a single value (last one not applicable to your case since you are incrementing array elements).
3. Similar to the previous one, false sharing happens when you update two distinct array elements that happen to be in the same cache line. For example, that seems likely in Q2, especially if the number of contributing factors is low.

What you can do is to sort and group your `localRows` by borough and date, then spread the computation over the groups. That will prevent true and false sharing issues while updating the aggregates in Q1 and Q3. As for the contributing factors in Q2, if they are not that many, use OpenMP reduction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've tried tuning a bit the chunk size N for dynamic scheduling but doesn't seems to affect much the execution times. Your suggestion seems brilliant but how would you implement this sort&group step? I suppose we can see this as a preprocessing step or something that can be inserted in the loading phase but wouldn't it increase the overall duration itself?

Comment: Without knowing the size or the distribution of your data, it is hard to give any concrete suggestions. But that's the thing with parallel computing - you either need your data in special structures that lend themselves to processing in parallel or you do some preprocessing and shape conversions that add overhead but then allow for faster consequent processing in parallel. It's a trade-off that may pay off or not depending on the case.

Comment: The size of the distribution is variable and goes from 0.5M rows to 5M rows (i'm doing a scalability analysis also based on this factor) and all tests I made are based on a 1M rows csv file. Anyhow, I've tried changing a bit the way each thread access the shared data (talking about output arrays for the three queries). For instance, every ```local_*``` array is now private to each thread and a reduction is performed at the end. What I'm experiencing now is quite interesting. This gets me a significant speed up for Q1 and Q2 but Q3 is still the same..

Comment: Looking deeper into this I've found that the "high weight" operation ```getWeek()``` is causing the issue. It almost looks like that, based on the number of times this function gets called, performance may degrade. Like there's a threshold over which parallelizing the loop is not convenient anymore. Is this behavior plausible? This happens even in previous scenario, without any reduction and modification.

Comment: I really don't get it: getWeek() doesn't depend on any shared data (so no false sharing casualties) and theoretically having 1 thread performing the same job 100 times vs 5 threads performing it 20 times each shouldn't be always faster?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't some hidden global state in `getWeek()`? Static variables perhaps?

Comment: This is the function [https://pastebin.com/8vY65eF6](https://pastebin.com/8vY65eF6) and I think there are no global/static vars used. Only other thing I can think of is the dictionary accesses but they gave no problem in Q2 in which their presence is even more frequent.

Comment: There is a change in global state involved - `mktime()` sets the external `tzname`.

Comment: Ok I was totally unaware of this.. This might be the real issue. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Write your own implementation of `mktime()`.

Comment: Also, use some tool that can find data races. I'd strongly recommend Intel VTune Profiler and Intel Inspector, both available for free now. The former analyses the multithreaded execution of your program and the latter detects race conditions and other correctness problems. Or Google's [ThreadSantizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html) that is part of Clang, although it may have trouble when used with OpenMP code.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it! I find it hard to make my own ```mktime``` implementation, maybe it's easier to find something else that can give me the same result without race conditions.

Comment: Yes, [`mktime()`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=time/mktime.c;h=63c82fc6a96848b1f1e34164e7ce696035635fc6;hb=HEAD) is quite complicated actually. And it touches not only one, but two global variables. There is a shorter version in [diet libc](https://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/). The source is in `libugly/timegm.c`, so it probably works with UTC only.

Comment: Thanks for the catch Hristo! Exploiting ```timegm.c``` was the ideal solution, now I'm experiencing an almost linear speedup with increasing number of threads, which it is what I was expecting in the first place. I'm closing the question, have a nice day.